# Should I learn Blazor instead of Angular or React

Tags: angular, reactjs, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, blazor

I used to design the Front-End of applications by MVC pages.
But i have decided to use one of Front-End designing frameworks.

Is Blazor the future of Front-End designing? should I forget about learning Angular or React and focus on Blazor?

Comment: The benefit of Blazor is you can do server and client side in .Net C#. Maintaining a project that is .Net + Angular or .Net + React can be more expensive as developers you hire also have to be nice with Javascript. However other similar previous Microsoft ideas like Silverlight turned out to be a total failure due to performance issues and restrictions imposed by the company.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No technology will be the future of the web ;). They just change too often. Specialize in one and get to know at least another one for comparison and knowledge. Some projects will be better done in Angular (it's a full application framework), some in React (it's a just a UI framework), and some in Blazor for easier development of back-end and front-end...

Comment: So do you think Blazor is a replacement for Angular and React?

Comment: Blazor works with ASP.NET and you use C# to code. Angular and React use JavaScript. Blazor is quite new. It's hard to describe the differences in a short comment ;).